# Issue with pyramid framework wit Python 3.3 version

Tags: python-3.x, pyramid

Could you please help me to solve below error while starting my pyramid project ?

```
c:\Python33\Scripts\v_env_testmvc_cmd\Scripts>activate
(v_env_testmvc_cmd) c:\Python33\Scripts\v_env_testmvc_cmd\Scripts>cd..
(v_env_testmvc_cmd) c:\Python33\Scripts\v_env_testmvc_cmd>cd ..
(v_env_testmvc_cmd) c:\Python33\Scripts>pserve.exe MyProject\development.ini --reload
Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\Python33\Scripts\pserve-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pyramid==1.5a3', 'console_scripts', 'pserve')()
  File "c:\Python33\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.49-py3.3.egg\pkg_resources.py", line 345, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "c:\Python33\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.49-py3.3.egg\pkg_resources.py", line 2382, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "c:\Python33\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.49-py3.3.egg\pkg_resources.py", line 2088, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "c:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pyramid-1.5a3-py3.3.egg\pyramid\scripts\pserve.py", line 31, in <module>
    from pyramid.paster import setup_logging
  File "c:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pyramid-1.5a3-py3.3.egg\pyramid\paster.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pyramid.scripting import prepare
  File "c:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pyramid-1.5a3-py3.3.egg\pyramid\scripting.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyramid.config import global_registries
  File "c:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pyramid-1.5a3-py3.3.egg\pyramid\config\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from webob.exc import WSGIHTTPException as WebobWSGIHTTPException
  File "c:\Python33\lib\site-packages\webob-1.3.1-py3.3.egg\webob\exc.py", line 1134, in <module>
    from paste import httpexceptions
  File "c:\Python33\lib\site-packages\paste-1.7.5.1-py3.3.egg\paste\httpexceptio ns.py", line 77, in <module>
    from paste.wsgilib import catch_errors_app
  File "c:\Python33\lib\site-packages\paste-1.7.5.1-py3.3.egg\paste\wsgilib.py", line 331
    raise exc_info[0], exc_info[1], exc_info[2]
                     ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Could you please help me to solve all this errors ?

File name which has this issue is: `C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\paste-1.7.5.1-py3.3.egg\paste\wsgilib.py`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use activate.  Instead set an environment variable to your virtual environment path and use that when invoking commands.  Details are in this [setup guide](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/master/quick_tutorial/requirements.html).  Alternatively, the master branch of the documentation has the "bleeding edge" for [Windows installation of Pyramid](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/master/narr/install.html#installing-pyramid-on-a-windows-system) that has been thoroughly tested by tutorial and meetup participants.

Once you have done that, then follow the process described in [Creating a Pyramid Project](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/master/narr/project.html).

Answer (score 0):

It was documentation issue and was solved . Resolved in latest documennts.
Thank you.