# Issue while installing pyramid with apache and mod_wsgi on windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, mod-wsgi, pyramid

I am trying to install a pyramid project on windows. The wsgi file contains:

```
import os, sys

baseDir='D:\myproject\hello'
configFile = os.path.join(baseDir, 'development.ini')

sys.path.append(baseDir)
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/var/www/.python-eggs'

from pyramid.paster import get_app, setup_logging
setup_logging(configFile)
application = get_app(configFile, 'main')
```

Here 'hello' is the project name(root). But while accessing it from browser, I get the following error:

```
 from pyramid.paster import get_app, setup_logging
 [Wed Jan 22 14:32:50 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ImportError: No module named  pyramid.paster
```

Can anyone help me to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

According to this pyramid [tutorial](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/modwsgi/index.html) your environment is rather uncommon and difficult to set up. Nevertheless you need a python environment with pyramid installed. Say hello to virtualenv. You did not mention any details about using it. Below you see how **WSGIDaemonProcess** is configured to path of **site-packages** of the Python which mod_wsgi will run. Do not manage sys.path in wsgi.py. Your file wsgi.py should be like

```
from pyramid.paster import get_app, setup_logging
configFile = 'D:\myproject\hello\develoment.ini'
setup_logging(configFile)
application = get_app(configFile, 'main')
```

Before running mod_wsgi, run the python interpreter you used to install pyramid and import pyramid code. If that raises ImportError you either use wrong python interpreter or there is no pyramid installed.

```
from pyramid.paster import get_app, setup_logging
```

An excerpt from the configuration shown at [mod_wsgi tutorial](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/modwsgi/index.html).

```
WSGIDaemonProcess pyramid user=chrism group=staff threads=4 \
   python-path=/your/path/to/python/lib/python2.X/site-packages
WSGIScriptAlias /myapp /your/path/to/project/pyramid.wsgi
```

Try starting with pyramid scaffolds to learn basic principles of pyramid applications. There is also detailed instruction about [running pyramid on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242773/issue-with-pyramid-framework-wit-python-3-3-version).